# Importing same library in different files creates compiler conflict

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, importerror, tsc

I'm trying to learn typescript and created a simple typescript node js server that has two endpoints. Trying to two unit test files and getting the following error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
test/endpoint2.test.ts:6:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'chai_1'.

6 const chai_1 = __importDefault(require("chai"));
        ~~~~~~

  test/endpoint.test.ts:6:7
    6 const chai_1 = __importDefault(require("chai"));
            ~~~~~~
    'chai_1' was also declared here.
```

Test file 1 (endpoint.test.ts):

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { app } from '../src/index';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Endpoint tests', () => {
    it('Ping endpoint should return status 200', (done) => {
        const msg = "hello";
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/ping')
            .query({
                "message": msg
            })
            .end((err, res) => {
                chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                chai.expect(res.body).to.have.property("env", "TEST")
                chai.expect(res.body).to.have.property("version", "1.0.0")
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Test file 2 (endpoint2.test.ts):

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { app } from '../src/index';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Endpoint2', () => {
    it('Hello world endpoint should return status 200', (done) => {
        const msg = "hello";
        chai.request(app)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample_ts_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --exec NODE_ENV=DEV 'ts-node' src/index.ts",
    "test": "ts-node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --exit --require ts-node/register test/**/*.test.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleDetection": "auto",
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Running test via package.json script

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ts-node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --exit --require ts-node/register test/**/*.test.ts"
  },
```

How do I tell the typescript compiler to not trip over imports in different files?

Tried:

1. Created a library file in test/libs that held all imports and then export those into the test files. Same error.
2. Tried flipping different tsconfig flags with no success
3. Tried replacing 'import' with 'require'. That worked but the IDE warned me not to do that. I think I should be able to use import.
4. All my google prompts took me into a very different direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when using CodeceptJS with Typescript. I had a custom script which creates Codecept configuration and runs the tests (as opposed to running directly with `npx codeceptjs`). I was able to narrow this down to Codecept (re)registering ts-node (see https://github.com/codeceptjs/CodeceptJS/blob/3.x/lib/config.js#L152).

What you can do is check if any of your dependencies are doing the same. If you manage to find the culprit see if there are any config options for that module which would allow you to disable this behavior.

There's an [issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/409) on ts-node's Github started way back in 2017 which contains some additional discussion on this. It also contains another possible [workaround](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/409#issuecomment-407228078) by overriding the register function although I can't say how safe that is (probably not ideal)