# typescript exports causing "error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable"

Tags: typescript, scope, export, declaration

After a long gap, I am updating an [old typescript project](https://github.com/TheSwanFactory/hclang/pull/152) to the modern versions of node et al.  After fixing a bunch of linter error, I am getting a strange error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/frames/frame.ts:28:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'frames_1'.

28 const frames_1 = require("../frames");
         ~~~~~~~~

  src/execute/eval-pipe.ts:4:7
    4 const frames_1 = require("../frames");
            ~~~~~~~~
    'frames_1' was also declared here.
```

This apparently due to the typescript compiler creating non-local variables from different import statements:

= frame.ts

```js
export {}
import * as _ from 'lodash'
import { MetaFrame, NilContext } from '../frames'
```

= eval-pipe.ts

```js
export {}
import { Context, Frame, NilContext } from '../frames'
```

How is this possible? I added `export {}` to each file to ensure everything is module-scoped.  Do I need a different configuration?

= tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test/**/*-spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

== UPDATE

If, as suggested, I remove `"require": "ts-node/register"`
from mocha_opts, I instead get the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/ernest/Developer/hclang/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /Users/ernest/Developer/hclang/src/execute/hc-eval.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/ernest/Developer/hclang/src/execute/hc-eval.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Which makes me wonder if this line `import chalk from 'chalk'` is malformed or not being interpreted correctly.

Comment: Seems similar to this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37459

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829187/importing-same-library-in-different-files-creates-compiler-conflict

> I had the same exact problem. "error TS2451:" which was solved by removing "require: ['ts-node/register']" from "mochaOpts" in my "wdio.conf.js" – 
Pablo Miranda
 Jun 22, 2021 at 19:03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this wasn't the "real" issue.  I believe I solved this one by enabling type: module in package.json, but that created a bunch of other (more real) problems that took a long time to (mostly) fix.

FWIW, here's the final config files I ended up with that solved (those) problems.  Oddly, there's a couple test files that still give weird .ts errors, but I can work around those for now.

## package.json (partial)

```json
  "type": "module",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "./lib",
    "src": "./src",
    "test": "./test"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

## .mocharc.json

```
{
  "extension": ["ts"],
  "require": "ts-node/register"
}
```